# How to zoom using gms.vision.CameraSource

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, zooming

I am using CameraSource to decode a barcode for my mobile app, everything is working perfectly but I would like to zoom the video from my camera. 
I have been reading the documentation of CameraSource but i can't find anything about zooming.
I am wondering if anyone knows how to apply zoom using google play api CameraSource, if it's not possible I will do without it.

Here is my activity code :

```
        cameraView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView)

        val detector = BarcodeDetector.Builder(applicationContext)
            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.EAN_13 or Barcode.EAN_8 or Barcode.UPC_A or Barcode.UPC_E)
            .build()

        cameraSource = CameraSource.Builder(this, detector)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
            .build()

        cameraView.holder.addCallback(object : SurfaceHolder.Callback {
            override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
                try {
                    cameraSource.start(surfaceView.holder)
                } catch (ie: Exception) {
                    Log.e("CAMERA SOURCE", ie.message)
                }
            }

            override fun surfaceChanged(
                holder: SurfaceHolder,
                format: Int,
                width: Int,
                height: Int
            ) {
            }

            override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
                cameraSource.stop()
            }
        })

        detector.setProcessor(object : Detector.Processor<Barcode> {
            override fun release() {}
            override fun receiveDetections(detections: Detections<Barcode>) {
                val barcodes = detections.detectedItems
                if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
                    detector.release()
                    val resultIntent = Intent(this@BarcodeActivity, AddFoodActivity::class.java)
                    resultIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_BARCODE", barcodes.valueAt(0).rawValue)
                    startActivity(resultIntent)
                    finish()
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Did you find the answer ?